# Time Limit Error on After Save Flow that sends out emails

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, batch, email-alert, timeout

[image]I need to create a flow that sends out a specific email alert when the Email_to_Send field changes. Email_to_Send is a picklist that has 10 different values. Each value has an email alert associated with it. When the value of Email_to_Send changes, I need to send out the email alert that corresponds with the value in the picklist. My flow only runs if the Email_to_Send field has been changed. I then have a decisional variable that checks the value of the Email_to_Send field and then sends out the appropriate email alert.

This works when I update up to 85 records at once. However, If I try to update more than 85 records in a list view at once, I receive a time limit error. I know I have a trigger that runs in the background whenever this record gets updated. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can bulkify this flow, that way I'd be able to have it send out emails when I update hundreds of records at once?

Comment: What's your flow look like right now? It could possibly be optimized.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have edited the question to include the flow. I originally thought it could have been due to some updates I am making. However, after deleting the updates and creation variables and only keeping the email alerts, the flow still times out.

Comment: That flow doesn't look "too" crazy. Are you sure though, that you're not running into an infinite loop or something? Have you tried setting up debug logs to see what takes the most time? I generally recommend setting up a profiling trace flag and see if you can identify which units are taking the most time. You'll find this in the Developer Console under Debug > Change Log Levels.

Comment: I have an after save trigger involved whenever these records get update. Is there a chance that when I do updates in this flow it is causing the trigger to execute multiple times? If so, is there a way of avoiding this?

Comment: Is this screenshot from your after save trigger - or is that a separate flow/apex? If it's separate, what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal and also happens to me as well. It's the Email Alert itself that causes this to happen. The Email Alert is not happening asynchronously, as such it slows down the processing of the flow significantly.

You can try to set the flow to have an asynchronous path and move all your flow logic underneath the asynchronous path instead. That should give the asynchronous execution more CPU time to work with to perform the email sends. You should be able to do this by clicking the "Play" button in the flow (first node of the flow) and hitting Edit at the top right corner there, then checking the "Include a Run Asynchronously path..." checkbox towards the bottom of the form there, then selecting all, copying, and pasting your existing flow items under the new async path and remove them all from the immediate path.